# Is this a known matrix function?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Consider a linear $n$-dimensional system $\mathbf{y} = A\mathbf{x}$, where the $n$ variables $x_i$ and the $n$ variables $y_i$ are related linearly by the matrix $A$ and $\det(A)\neq 0$. For example let's say we have $2+2$ variables:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
y_0\\
y_1
\end{pmatrix} 
=
\begin{pmatrix}
A_{00} & A_{01}\\
A_{10} & A_{11}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_0\\
x_1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

If we want to write $\mathbf{x}$ as a linear function of $\mathbf{y}$, we would use the inverse of $A$, i.e. $\mathbf{x} = A^{-1}\mathbf{y}$. So far all pretty standard.

But also other partitions of the set of $2n$ variables in two halves can be related linearly, e.g.
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x_0\\
y_1
\end{pmatrix} = f(A)
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
y_0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
could be well-defined. Is $f$ a known thing? For an $n$-dimensional system, what is $f$ given two halves (if it exists)?

EDIT:
I've noticed using block inversion that the solution given by @Fishbane should be equivalent to

$$
f(A) = (V_4-AV_2)^{-1}(AV_1-V_3)
$$
where the $V_i$ blocks are defined in the answer. This is a matrix version of the Möbius transform.

Comment: What do you mean by any two halves must be related linearly. For example if $A=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ then $f(A)$ is not defined.

Comment: yes good point, I will edit the question

Comment: I'm still not understanding. $f(A)$ is only defined if some explicit relationship exists between opposing diagonals, where $f(A)$ is that relationship.

Comment: @vertex yes, indeed. Some of these relationships are known, e.g. if you swap the roles of $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ then $f=(\,\cdot\,)^{-1}$. Is there a systematic way of defining others?

Comment: I think I have an answer, it will take a bit for me to write up. Have you heard of pseudoinverses before?

Comment: The second term in your _Mobius_ expression has a sign error. It should read $$\large{f(A) = (V_4-AV_2)^{-1}(AV_1-V_3)}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We will consider the case of an $n\times n$ matrix $A$. (I believe this could be extended to non-square matrices fairly easily, but it requires some care) I will use block matrix notation extensively.

First consider that the set of points $\begin{bmatrix}x \\y \end{bmatrix}\in\Bbb{R}^{2n}$ such that $y=Ax$. This set is a linear subspace. Call it $\mathcal{S}$. It should be easy to see that $\mathcal{S}$ is spanned by the columns of the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}I\\A\end{bmatrix}$.

We want a linear relationship $\mathcal{L}:\mathcal{X}\to\mathcal{Y}$  where $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ are $n$-dimensional subspaces of $\Bbb{R}^{2n}$, such that $\mathcal{X}+\mathcal{Y}\subseteq$ span $\left(\begin{bmatrix}I\\A\end{bmatrix}\right)$. (Clearly $\mathcal{L}$ does not always exist and may not be well-defined, but we shall for now assume it is fine.)

Define a matrix $V:=\begin{bmatrix}V_1 & V_2\\V_3 & V_4\end{bmatrix}$ such that $\begin{bmatrix}V_1\\V_3\end{bmatrix}=$ basis of $\mathcal{X}$, and $\begin{bmatrix}V_2\\V_4\end{bmatrix}=$ basis of $\mathcal{Y}$.

(For example, in the case in your question, $V=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1&0\\1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$, and in general if you are only swapping coordinates $V$ will be a permutation matrix.)

For any $\begin{bmatrix}x \\y \end{bmatrix}\in\mathcal{S}$, we have some $\hat{x}\in\mathcal{X},\hat{y}\in\mathcal{Y}$ such that $\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}V_1 & V_2\\V_3 & V_4\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\hat{x}\\\hat{y}\end{bmatrix}$, and some $\hat{v}\in\Bbb{R}^n$ such that $\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}I\\A\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}v\end{bmatrix}$. We are looking for $f(A)$ such that $\hat{y}=f(A)\hat{x}$. Therefore

$$\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}V_1 & V_2\\V_3 & V_4\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\hat{x}\\\hat{y}\end{bmatrix}&=\begin{bmatrix}I\\A\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}v\end{bmatrix}\\
\begin{bmatrix}V_1\\V_3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\hat{x}\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}V_2\\V_4\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\hat{y}\end{bmatrix}&=\begin{bmatrix}I\\A\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}v\end{bmatrix}\\
\begin{bmatrix}V_1\\V_3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\hat{x}\end{bmatrix}&=\begin{bmatrix}I\\A\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}v\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}V_2\\V_4\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\hat{y}\end{bmatrix}\\
\begin{bmatrix}V_1\\V_3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\hat{x}\end{bmatrix}&=\begin{bmatrix}I & -V_2\\A & -V_4\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}v\\\hat{y}\end{bmatrix}.\\
\end{align}$$

Fixing $\hat{x}$, this is a linear equation in $\begin{bmatrix}v\\\hat{y}\end{bmatrix}$ and so if there are solutions we can use pseudoinverses to find a solution given by $$\begin{bmatrix}v\\\hat{y}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}I & -V_2\\A & -V_4\end{bmatrix}^+\begin{bmatrix}V_1\\V_3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\hat{x}\end{bmatrix}.$$

Thus if $f(A)$ is well defined then
$$f(A)= \text{last }n\text{ rows of }\begin{bmatrix}I & -V_2\\A & -V_4\end{bmatrix}^+\begin{bmatrix}V_1\\V_3\end{bmatrix}.$$

We can check for correctness by using the tests used to normally check if a pseudoinverse is giving correct answers. Alternatively if you haven't encountered pseudoinverses before they can be replaced by inverses as long as they are defined, additionally if they are defined you do not need to perform any further checks.

Comment: I am adding this as a comment as I haven't fully checked it, but it seems that if $f(A)$ is well defined (that is it exists and is unique) then under weak assumptions (I believe it suffices for the collumns of $V$ to be a basis) $\begin{bmatrix}I & -V_2\\A & -V_4\end{bmatrix}$ is always invertible. (That is $\begin{bmatrix}I & -V_2\\A & -V_4\end{bmatrix}$ is invertible iff $f(A)$ is well defined)

Comment: It's a cool answer (and seems to match what I get in the $2\times2$ special case). To improve the write up, in your second and third paragraph you can start to give names to the subspaces and the linear map like $\mathcal{L}:\mathcal{X}\to\mathcal{Y}$ using `$\mathcal{L}:\mathcal{X}\to\mathcal{Y}$`

Comment: @BenjaminWang Thanks. I'll probably neaten things up a bit at some point but I'm somewhat busy at the moment so it might be a while. If you are able to edit and you want to, feel free to modify anything or write your own answer.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks

Comment: I think using block inversion your solution is equivalent to $(V_4-AV_2)^{-1}(V_3+AV_1)$

Comment: @Ziofil That looks correct, however the correct formula is $(V_4-AV_2)^{-1}(AV_1-V_3)$. In fact this formula hints at a much simpler derivation when it is rerarranged.

Comment: @Fishbane what do you reckon the simpler derivation looks like?

Comment: @BenjaminWang I am currently writing a second answer using the simpler derivation and also dealing with the general cases for non-square $A$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $A$ is an $n\times m$ matrix. As in the previous answer we consider linear subspaces $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ along with a linear map $\mathcal{L}:\mathcal{X}\rightarrow\mathcal{Y}$ such that for all $\tilde{x}\in\mathcal{X}$, $\tilde{x}+\mathcal{L}(\tilde{x})$ is in the linear subspace spanned by the columns of $\begin{bmatrix}I\\A\end{bmatrix}$ where $I$ is the $m\times m$ identity matrix. (We shall assume $\mathcal{X}$ is $r$-dimensional and $\mathcal{Y}$ is $k$-dimensional).

Again following the previous answer we define $V:=\begin{bmatrix}V_1&V_2\\V_3&V_4\end{bmatrix}$ such that $\begin{bmatrix}V_1\\V_3\end{bmatrix}$ is a basis of $\mathcal{X}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}V_2\\V_4\end{bmatrix}$ is a basis of $\mathcal{Y}$. (Note that $V_1$ is $m\times k$ and $V_4$ is $n\times r$).

Now let $\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}V_1\\V_3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\hat{x}\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}V_2\\V_4\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\hat{y}\end{bmatrix}$, from this we conclude $x=V_1\hat{x}+V_2\hat{y}$ and $y=V_3\hat{x}+V_4\hat{y}$. (Where $\hat{x}$ is the coordinate representation of a vector in $\mathcal{X}$ according to the basis, and similarly for $\hat{y}$)

Now if $\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$ is in the span of the columns of $\begin{bmatrix}I\\A\end{bmatrix}$ then we have;

$$\begin{align}
y&=Ax\\
V_3\hat{x}+V_4\hat{y}&=A(V_1\hat{x}+V_2\hat{y})\\
V_3\hat{x}+V_4\hat{y}&=AV_1\hat{x}+AV_2\hat{y}\\
V_4\hat{y}-AV_2\hat{y}&=AV_1\hat{x}-V_3\hat{x}\\
(V_4-AV_2)\hat{y}&=(AV_1-V_3)\hat{x}\\
\end{align}$$

Now assuming that $(V_4-AV_2)$ is square and invertible we conclude that $\hat{y}=(V_4-AV_2)^{-1}(AV_1-V_3)\hat{x}$.

Therefore the matrix for $\mathcal{L}$ is given by $(V_4-AV_2)^{-1}(AV_1-V_3)$. (i.e. $f(A)=(V_4-AV_2)^{-1}(AV_1-V_3)$).

We now consider the general case. Using generalized inverses we can see that if there is a solution we have $\hat{y}=(V_4-AV_2)^{+}(AV_1-V_3)\hat{x}$.

Now assuming that there is a unique linear map $\mathcal{L}$ we can use standard results about solving linear relations using generalized inverses to conclude that $I-(V_4-AV_2)^{+}(V_4-AV_2)=0$ (as otherwise there would be multiple solutions).

By examining ranks we can see that this is only possible if $(V_4-AV_2)$ has full column rank, and in fact it is always true if $(V_4-AV_2)$ has full column rank.

(As an aside this tells us that if $(V_4-AV_2)$ is square then $\mathcal{L}$ exists iff $(V_4-AV_2)$ is invertible).

Finally we can determine if the solution is valid by again using standard results to conclude that the solution is valid iff $(V_4-AV_2)(V_4-AV_2)^{+}(AV_1-V_3)=(AV_1-V_3)$.

Thus $\mathcal{L}$ exists iff $(V_4-AV_2)$ has full column rank and $(V_4-AV_2)(V_4-AV_2)^{+}(AV_1-V_3)=(AV_1-V_3)$. And if it exists $f(A)=(V_4-AV_2)^{+}(AV_1-V_3)$.