# Has variable shuffling in linear maps been studied?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, linear-transformations, boundary-value-problem, cauchy-problem

Specifically, say I have a linear map $\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$. I want to construct from it a map between a regrouping of the vector spaces. Concretely, I start with
\begin{align}
  \left[\begin{array}{c}
    x' \\
    y'
  \end{array}\right] &= \left[\begin{array}{cc}
    a & b \\
    c & d
  \end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
    x \\
    y
  \end{array}\right].
\end{align}

Has the process of finding the map that this implies from $(y,y')$ to $(x,x')$ been studied? Does it have a name?

Comment: What’s the reason for finding such map?

Comment: Studying second order ordinary differential equations and the relationship between solutions to the initial value problem (Cauchy data) and the boundary value problems (Dirichlet/Neumann).

Comment: The question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4524394/is-this-a-known-matrix-function/4524421#comment9511204_4524421 asks about the same thing. In the answers and comments we were able to determine in general what these maps look like (and when they exist and are unique). Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Constructing the map is straightforward. One way to do this is to break the matrix up into equations, invert one of them, and reconstruct the matrix relationship. Inverting the bottom equation gives:
$$ x = c^{-1} y' - d c^{-1}y. $$
This changes the top equation to:
$$ x' = ac^{-1} y' + (b - adc^{-1})y, $$
thus:
\begin{align}
  \left[\begin{array}{c}
    x \\
    x'
  \end{array}\right] &= \left[\begin{array}{cc}
    -dc^{-1} & c^{-1} \\
    b - adc^{-1} & ac^{-1}
  \end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
    y \\
    y'
  \end{array}\right].
\end{align}

I think the most fitting name for this process would be *transverse*, since it is similar, visually, to transposing the inputs and outputs of the equation. Obviously, the necessary and sufficient condition for this transverse to exist is for $c\neq0$.

Comment: Your answer appears to be missing a factor of $a$ in the lower left element of the matrix. The correct entry should be $b-adc^{-1}$.

Comment: @Fishbane Thanks! That makes the inverse-transverse match the reordered transverse. :)